# Ambiguous behavior by Get-ChildItem cmdlet in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I'm trying to get a list of all txt files in a local folder.

```
$dir = "C:\report\"
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -File -Include "*.txt"
```

Above code returns nothing, However when I add wildcard `*` in front of the path, the command works as expected and returns the list of txt files.

```
$dir = "C:\report\*"
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -File -Include "*.txt"
```

Without the `-Include "*.txt"` parameter, I get list of all files in both the cases (*System.IO.FileInfo* object)

I'm wondering why adding `-Include "*.txt"` is causing this ambiguous behavior?
I'm new to PowerShell and I'm using Powershell 7.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Include` parameter works when combined with the`Recurse`  switch, OR as you have noticed by appending `\*` to the path, which implies recursion.

If you do not want the cmdlet to recurse through subfolders, use `-Filter '*.txt'` instead.